# RUSAGE_THREAD Does not work, looking for solution/alternative

Tags: c++, linux, ace

I am trying to calculate Avg cpu time of a certain thread, using rusage.

however, i am getting ‘RUSAGE_THREAD’ was not declared in this scope.

i am using

```
#include <sys/resource.h>
```

and compiling with -D_GNU_SOURCE

at the start of my code, and my Linux version is fine.

this is where i try to do the calculation:

```
struct rusage l_rusage;
int retVal = getrusage(RUSAGE_THREAD, &l_rusage);

u64 userUSeconds = (static_cast<u64>(l_rusage.ru_utime.tv_sec)) * 1000000 +
  (static_cast<u64>(l_rusage.ru_utime.tv_usec));

u64 systemUSeconds = (static_cast<u64>(l_rusage.ru_stime.tv_sec)) * 1000000 +
  (static_cast<u64>(l_rusage.ru_stime.tv_usec));

return (userUSeconds + systemUSeconds) / ACE_OS::num_processors_online();
```

Any ideas? or maybe even a different solution? i am using ACE libs as well, so i have the ACE_OS, but i couldn't find the equivalent for RUSAGE_THREAD when trying to use ACE_OS::rusage.

Thank you

EDIT: Also another thing, i cant access to where the thread making code is actually, i can only use code from within the thread.

Comment: Please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us, seeing code always helps.

Answer (score 1):

The [manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getrusage.2.html) says you need to define the macro `_GNU_SOURCE` not `__USE_GNU`.

Comment: My bad, but this still wont work, same error, moved the define to the makefile to make sure it is defined before every thing else.

Comment: @Dinari did you find a solution to this problem?

Comment: Was a long time ago, so i'm not sure, however I had this followup question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36181225/impossible-cpu-time-for-process-thread-with-rusage  which include code examples to to do what I intended to.